# How to open QGIS attribute table in form view using Python?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, attribute-table

I've got a plugin where I load some layers. After the last layer loaded, I show the attribute table.

However, I would like to select the form view and not the table view (see image).

How can I do this in Python?

[image: Attribute table layout options]

Answer (score 3):

On QGIS v.2.6 you can open the Attribute table in form view (attribute editor) mode, this way:

1. Load a layer into QGIS and make it active (that is, click on its name in the ToC).
2. Open the QGIS Python console.
3. Paste the following code snippet there:

   ```
   from qgis.gui import QgsDualView
   dv = QgsDualView()
   dv.init( iface.activeLayer(), iface.mapCanvas() )
   dv.setView( QgsDualView.AttributeEditor )
   dv.show()
   ```

And you get (yeah, I know it lacks the toolbar at the top, but that's the most you can get from PyQGIS :D) this:

[image]